# Iterator on several sets

Tags: java, graph, iterator

I am writing a Graph class,

I keep a `HashMap` in which ids of nodes (int values) are mapped to the associated nodes, and I'm using `adjacency list` approach to keep edges starting from a node (keeping them in form of a `HashSet`)

Note that : This graph is directed and unweighted,

I want to implement a method which returns an iterator over objects of class `Edge` :

When getting next on this iterator , one will get an object of class Edge which is created right when it's being traversed, and if there's no more neighbors for a node, it goes to the next node (order is not important) and if there's no more starting nodes (all are traversed), it finishes.

Any idea on how to implement this iterator on the edges without previously keeping the edges in Edge class objects ?

```
class Graph{
    HashMap<Integer , GraphNode> nodes;
    public Graph(){
        nodes = new HashMap<Integer ,GraphNode>();
    }
    public boolean addEdge(GraphNode n1 , GraphNode n2){
        if (!nodes.containsKey(n1) || !nodes.containsKey(n2))
            return false;
        return n1.addNeighbor(n2);
    }
    public boolean addNode(int id){
        if (nodes.containsKey(id))
            return false;
        nodes.put(id , new GraphNode(id));
        return true;
    }
    public boolean removeNode(GraphNode n1){
        if (!nodes.containsKey(n1.content))
            return false;
        for (GraphNode m : n1.neighbors)
            m.removeNeighbor(n1);
        nodes.remove(n1);
        return false;
    }
    public boolean removeEdge(GraphNode n1 , GraphNode n2){
        if (!nodes.containsKey(n1) || !nodes.containsKey(n2))
            return false;
        return n1.removeNeighbor(n2);
    }
    public Iterator<GraphNode> NodeIterator(){
        return nodes.values().iterator();
    }


   public Iterator<Edge> EdgeIterator(){
        Iterator<GraphNode> itr = this.NodeIterator();
        while (itr.hasNext){
            GraphNode n = itr.next();
            //......

        }
    }

}
class GraphNode{
    HashSet<GraphNode> neighbors;
    int content;
    public GraphNode(int content){
        this.content = content;
        neighbors = new HashSet<GraphNode>();
    }
    boolean addNeighbor(GraphNode n){
        if (neighbors.contains(n))
            return false;
        neighbors.add(n);
        return true;
    }
    boolean removeNeighbor(GraphNode n){
        if (!neighbors.contains(n))
            return false;
        neighbors.remove(n);
        return true;
    }


   }

class Edge{
    Node start , end;
    public Edge(Node start , Node end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to implement?

Comment: It's now updated , I want to update the iterator I explained about

Comment: What is the graph type you want to implement?

Comment: It's a general question , I'm more interested to know if it's possible to implement such an iterator, you can check the method I want to implement if you scroll the code down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might work :

```
public Iterator<Edge> EdgeIterator(){
    Iterator <Edge> edgeIter = new Iterator<Edge>() {

        private Iterator<GraphNode> itr = this.NodeIterator();
        private GraphNode currentNode;
        ... // additional private members as required

        public void remove()
        {
          // you don't have to implement this method if you don't need to support
          // this operation
        }

        public Edge next()
        {
          if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException ();

          return new Edge (x , y); // where you find x & y based on the current state 
                                   // of the iterator (kept in the private members of 
                                   // this instance)
        }

        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return ?; // you return a boolean value based on the current state 
                      // of the iterator (kept in the private members of 
                      // this instance)
        }
    };

    return edgeIter;
}
```

The `EdgeIterator` method creates an `Iterator<Edge>` and defines the methods of the `Iterator` interface (I left the implementation of these methods to you). The `Iterator` instance contains an instance of `Iterator<GraphNode>`, which it uses to iterate over the nodes.

You should add to the iterator some additional private members that keep track of the current node (the last node returned by the node iterator) and the current edge you are iterating on. Whenever you finish iterating over the edges of a node, you get the next node using `itr.next()` (after checking there is a next node available). `next()` of the edge iterator can construct the next `Edge` based on those private members.

Comment: Would you take a look at my code ? to see if it's correct or not

Answer (score 0):

As Eran said , I completed the code of the iterator methods ,
Do you think this one works ?

```
public Iterator<Edge> EdgeIterator(){
    Iterator<Edge> edgeIter = new Iterator<Edge>() {

        private Iterator<GraphNode> node_itr = NodeIterator();
        private Iterator<GraphNode> neighbor_itr;
        private GraphNode current_node;
        private GraphNode current_neighbor;
        public void remove()
        {
            if (current_node == null || current_neighbor == null)
                return;
            current_node.removeNeighbor(current_neighbor);
        }
        public Edge next()
        {
            if (neighbor_itr == null || !neighbor_itr.hasNext())
                if (node_itr.hasNext()){
                    current_node = node_itr.next();
                    neighbor_itr = current_node.neighbors.iterator();
                }else
                    return null;
            current_neighbor = neighbor_itr.next();
            return new Edge(current_node , current_neighbor);
        }
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            if (neighbor_itr == null || !neighbor_itr.hasNext())
                if (node_itr.hasNext())
                    return node_itr.next().neighbors.iterator().hasNext();
                else
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
    };

    return edgeIter;
}
```

**Update** : The edited/working version :

```
public Iterator<Edge> EdgeIterator(){
    Iterator<Edge> edgeIter = new Iterator<Edge>() {
        private Iterator<GraphNode> node_itr = NodeIterator();
        private Iterator<GraphNode> neighbor_itr;
        private GraphNode current_node;
        private GraphNode current_neighbor;
        public void remove()
        {
            if (current_node == null || current_neighbor == null)
                return;
            current_node.removeNeighbor(current_neighbor);
        }
        private void moveNext(){
            if (neighbor_itr == null || !neighbor_itr.hasNext()){
                while (node_itr.hasNext()){
                    current_node = node_itr.next();
                    neighbor_itr = current_node.neighbors.iterator();
                    if (neighbor_itr.hasNext()){
                        break;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
        public Edge next()
        {
            moveNext();
            current_neighbor = neighbor_itr.next();
            return new Edge(current_node , current_neighbor);
        }
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            moveNext();
            return neighbor_itr.hasNext();
        }
    };

    return edgeIter;
}
```

Comment: You have several bugs : 1. In `hasNext()` you advance the `node_itr` without storing the result, which means if you call `hasNext()` followed by `next()`, you'll skip a node. To avoid that, `hasNext()` should store the result of `node_iter.next()` in `current_node` (and also initialize `neighbor_itr` in this case). 2. In both `next()` and `hasNext()` you don't handle the case where a new node returned by the iterator has no neighbors (in which case you should move to the next node, until you find a node with edges or reach the last node).

Comment: Yes , you are right , actually I updated the code , but I don't know where to post it , I added a new method called `moveNext()` which moves to the next node which has at least one neighbor (in case currently the `neighbor_itr` is null or it doesn't have `next`), but I don't iterate through the neighbors, at the beginning of `hasNext()` and `next` this method is called

Comment: Why don't you edit your answer to show the fixed version of the code? I hope your code works now.